# Sending email using Zend Framework and PHP

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, send

I working on a form whereby when the user enter in their email account and click on send, an email will be sent to their email account.

I have everything worked out. Just that it doesnt send the email to my account. Anyone have any ideas? Is there a configuration that I left out or something?

This is the sample from my controller:

```
public function retrieveemailAction(){

    $users = new Users();
    $email = $_POST['email'];                
    $view = Zend_Registry::get('view'); 

    if($users->checkEmail($_POST['email'])) {

        // The Subject
        $subject = "Email Test";

        // The message
        $message = "this is a test";            

        // Send email
        // Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
        // Use if command to display email message status
        if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            $view->operation = 'true';
        }            
    } else {
         $view->operation = 'false';
    }

    $view->render('retrieve.tpl');
}
```

Comment: you will need to have special configs done if you are testing your code on localhost.

Comment: what do you mean special configs? is there an example or something?

Answer (score 27):

I recommend you use `Zend_Mail` instead of `mail()`. It handles a lot of stuff automatically and just works great.

Do you have a SMTP server? Trying to send mail without your own SMTP server could be causing the mail to not be sent.

This is what I use for sending mails using `Zend_Mail` and Gmail:

In `Bootstrap.php`, I configure a default mail transport:

```
protected function _initMail()
{
    try {
        $config = array(
            'auth' => 'login',
            'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'port' => 587
        );

        $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
    } catch (Zend_Exception $e){
        //Do something with exception
    }
}
```

Then to send an email I use the following code:

```
//Prepare email
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo($email);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($message);
$mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'User Name');

//Send it!
$sent = true;
try {
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e){
    $sent = false;
}

//Do stuff (display error message, log it, redirect user, etc)
if($sent){
    //Mail was sent successfully.
} else {
    //Mail failed to send.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would switch to using Zend_Mail. Second i would use a real mail account on an smtp server somewhere and send from that. A lot of times there are restrictions on sending from the server itself, but using an actual mail server usually fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very useful screencast covering Zend_Mail available on ZendCasts
http://www.zendcasts.com/introduction-to-zend_mail/2010/02/

Answer (score 1):

In line `$mail->setBody($message);`, change it to `$mail->setBodyText($message);`