# Is there a faster way to retrieve a message using zend framework libraries?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, imap, optimization

Hi guys I'm building a simple mail interface for my application but I've noticed that its really slow especially when the user has to list out a number of emails. I've traced the time taken for code to execute and found that just the $mail->getMessage function takes around 0.6 seconds to execute.

My code is as below:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array(
                'host' => $current_dept->incoming_server,
                'ssl' =>($current_dept->imap_ssl == 'Y' ? true : false), // $current_dept('imap_ssl'),
                'port'=>$current_dept->incoming_port,
                'folder'=>$options->box,
                'user' =>$current_dept->email,
                'password' =>$current_dept->email_psd));
.....
$one_message = $mail->getMessage($i); //<-- this takes forever about 0.5 seconds
```

COnsider that this code is running in a loop i.e the fetch message part and for each message an overhead time of 0.5 seconds is too much. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is there any chance its your mail server thats taking this time to respond? There is no reason for the code to take that long other then waiting on something.

Comment: That could be a possibility - how can I speed this up?

Comment: It's almost certainly slow because the PHP code is waiting on the IMAP server.  I'm not sure what is considered "acceptable" to the various maintainers of IMAP server code, but you should look at speeding up the IMAP server itself.

Comment: I don't think thats a possibility as the IMAP server here is gmail...

Comment: And Gmail is not that fast the majority of the time.

Comment: ! Yow so I can't do much about it? WHats the best way to deal with this - how do webclients handle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are experienced with speed problems and sending use PEAR package from [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/). Using Mail-MIME can be very slow due to encoding implementation is slow (base64 used in Zend_Mail).

Or look maybe help this for you [Sending email using Zend Framework and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278095/sending-email-using-zend-framework-and-php)