# Send mail in Zend Framework showing an exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp, sendmail

I am trying to send an email in zend framework on localhost.

Following is my code :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        $mail->addTo($email);
        $mail->setSubject('Welcome');
        $mail->setFrom('test@user.com', 'test@user.com');
        $mail->setBodyText($bodyText);
        $sent = true;

        // Send the email
        try {
            $mail->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e);
            exit;
            $sent = false;
        }
        return $sent;
```

But its showing the following exception :

> [message:protected] => Unable to send mail. mail() [function.mail]:
>   Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Following is my setting in php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25


; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = test@user.com
```

I am using PHP Version 5.3.9, Wampserver 2.2.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

try this link how to send mail using localhost

```
//Prepare email
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo($email);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($message);
$mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'User Name');

//Send it!
$sent = true;
try {
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e){
    $sent = false;
}

//Do stuff (display error message, log it, redirect user, etc)
if($sent){
    //Mail was sent successfully.
} else {
    //Mail failed to send.
}
```

or try this link [Sending email using Zend Framework and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278095/sending-email-using-zend-framework-and-php)

Comment: These all are for php `mail()` function. I am using zend frameworks `send();` method

Comment: ok....What should I put in `SMTP` in `phi.ini` file? I mean localhost or something else

Comment: try http://www.techchorus.net/using-smtp-zend-framework-solve-email-delivery-problem or http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.smtp-authentication.html